# Hindi font is not proper rendering on webview browser using javafx

Tags: java, webview, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-webengine

I am using webview component in javafx 2.0. Problem is that, web view is not  rendering properly hindi font in the webview.Same code is rendering properly in some system, but not rendering on others. so plz give me any suggession. Or is there any alternative  to webview.

Following is the javafx code that i am using to render hindi font:-

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TestWebView extends Application {

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

     WebView myBrowser = new WebView();

      WebEngine myWebEngine = myBrowser.getEngine();
      myWebEngine.load("http://www.jagran.com/");

      StackPane root = new StackPane();
      root.getChildren().add(myBrowser);
      primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100, 100));
      primaryStage.show();
  }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you check if you can provide something like charset or encoding parameter anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

you can use jxbrower for this issues. Please look this example

```
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.Browser;
import com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.javafx.BrowserView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * Demonstrates how to embed Browser instance into JavaFX application.
 */
public class JavaFXSample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Browser browser = new Browser();
        BrowserView browserView = new BrowserView(browser);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(browserView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        browser.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanku  Rajesh,  its a right code. But JXBrowser is not free, and the price of this browser is 120000.... So plz give me anothere solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

1.) JCEF > https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef

2.) use java8 , iguess you are using java7 then only you are facing the issue.

```
package javafxapplication5;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication5 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        WebView view = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        engine.load("http://www.jagran.com/");
        root.getChildren().add(view);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

this works for me.

Comment: Yes i used java8, but video player is not woking properly in java 8.